# Google Analytics - Exclude Authenticated Users

Tags: google-analytics

We run a SaaS platform with a cross-domain setup:

- [www.site.com](http://www.site.com) is the presentation website
- client-subdomain.site.com is the client area

On the presentation website we have a login page where users can authenticate and they are then redirected to their subdomain.

The challenge here is to create a segment with only the users that have never authenticated. So as soon as a user lands on any subdomain of site.com I would like all their traffic on the presentation website ([www.site.com](http://www.site.com)) to be excluded. We need this to properly differentiate between users of our client companies vs. new visitors and potential clients.

**Example 1**

User A lands on homepage

They go to the login page

They go back to the homepage

-> Result: their traffic is considered

**Example 2**

User B lands on homepage

They go to the login page

They login and then land on **some-client.site.com**

-> All their following traffic on [www.site.com](http://www.site.com) is excluded

How would this best be achieved?

P.S. Removing the GA script from the subdomains is not an option as we need to analyze that traffic as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Analytics Property of `www.site.com` and `client-subdomain.site.com` is the same, just send an information to Analytics when user is logged.

There are several ways as userId, custom dimension or simply just an event (for example with `category: 'loggedin'`). Then you have to create a segment (`Advanced ---> Conditions`) in Google Analytics that **includes Users who have an event with that category**.

Comment: Ended up implementing a new segment based on an event triggered on the client subdomains. Thank you!